# WinSock accept() returning 204.204.204.204

Tags: c++, multithreading, networking, winsock

Trying to create a simple WinSock server - accept() just keeps returning the IP of 204.204.204.204. My online search results show a lot of people get this error from not giving a sockaddr length (3rd accept() param) but I already am.

Been struggling for a long time; I have no doubt that I have made a simple mistake but I just can't spot it!

PS. I know I have a few unused variables being passed about and stuff - Work in progress :)

**Network.h:::**

```
#pragma once
#include <afxwin.h>
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <functional>
#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "Connection.h"
using namespace std;

#define LISTEN_PORT 20248
#define MAX_CLIENTS 10

typedef struct NETWORK_T
{
    SOCKET c_socket;            // Client Socket
    sockaddr_in addr_in;        // Addr_in
    fd_set set;                 // Used to check if data in socket
    int i;                      // Additional info
} CLIENT, SERVER;

class Network
{
public:
    Network(void);
    ~Network(void);
    void StartListenServer(string port, function<void(Connection)> callback);
    void StopListenServer(void);
    void Connect(string ip, string port);

private:
    bool mServerRunning;
    WSADATA mData;
    SERVER* mServer;

    static UINT ServerThread(LPVOID pParam);

    bool Setup(SERVER* server, WSADATA& data);
    void ServerCloseSocket(NETWORK_T* socket);
    void ServerCloseSocket(SOCKET& socket);
};
```

**Network.CPP:::**

```
#include "Network.h"


Network::Network(void)
{
    mServerRunning = false;
}


Network::~Network(void)
{

}

void Network::StartListenServer(string port, function<void(Connection)> callback)
{
    if(mServerRunning)
        return;         // If server is running we dont want a second

    mServerRunning = true;
    AfxBeginThread(ServerThread, this);
}

void Network::StopListenServer(void)
{
    mServerRunning = false;
}

void Network::Connect(string ip, string port)
{

}

void Network::ServerCloseSocket(NETWORK_T* socket)
{
    shutdown(socket->c_socket, 2);
    closesocket(socket->c_socket);
}

void Network::ServerCloseSocket(SOCKET& socket)
{
    shutdown(socket, 2);
    closesocket(socket);
}

bool Network::Setup(SERVER* server, WSADATA& data)
{
    int res;

    server->addr_in.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server->addr_in.sin_port = htons(LISTEN_PORT);
    server->addr_in.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    res = WSAStartup(0x101, &data);
    if (res != 0)
    {
        cout << "WSAStartup failed.\r\n";
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "WSAStartup Version: " << data.wVersion << "\nWSADescription: " << data.szDescription << "\nWSAStatus: " << data.szSystemStatus << "\r\n";
    }
    server->c_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (server->c_socket == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        cout << "Invalid socket.\r\n";
        return false;
    }
    else if (server->c_socket == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        cout << "Socket error.\r\n";
        return false;
    }
    else
        cout << "Server socket established.\r\n";
    res = 1;
    setsockopt(server->c_socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (char*)&res, sizeof(res));   // Allows the socket to be bound to an address that is already in use
    res = ::bind(server->c_socket, (struct sockaddr*)&server->addr_in, sizeof(struct sockaddr));
    if (res != 0)
    {
        cout << "Socket BIND failed.\r\n";
        return false;
    }
    else
        cout << "Socket bound to port " << LISTEN_PORT << "\r\n";
    res = listen(server->c_socket, MAX_CLIENTS);
    cout << "Server listen mode: " << res << "\nMax clients: " << MAX_CLIENTS << "\r\n";
    res = 1;
    ioctlsocket(server->c_socket, FIONBIO, (u_long*)&res);

    return true;
}

UINT Network::ServerThread(LPVOID pParam)
{
    Network* ntwkPtr = (Network*)pParam;

    ntwkPtr->mServer = new SERVER();

    ntwkPtr->Setup(ntwkPtr->mServer, ntwkPtr->mData);

    SOCKET client;
    SOCKADDR_IN from;
    int fromlen = sizeof(from);

    while(ntwkPtr->mServerRunning)
    {
        char temp[512];
        client = accept(ntwkPtr->mServer->c_socket, (struct sockaddr*)&from, &fromlen); 
        sprintf(temp,"Your IP is %s\r\n",inet_ntoa(from.sin_addr));
        send(client,temp,strlen(temp),0);
        cout << "Connection from " << inet_ntoa(from.sin_addr) <<"\r\n";
        //ntwkPtr->ServerCloseSocket(client);
    }

    ntwkPtr->ServerCloseSocket(ntwkPtr->mServer);
    WSACleanup();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're passing `&fromlen` to `accept()`. I think you need to be passing just `fromlen`.

Comment: Check that `accept` has returned success, because if not there's no address to report.

Comment: Its definitely a pointer Mike.

Ah I had set the ports to non blocking then wasn't checking for success, I thought they were blocking. Thanks Steve! If you want to do an Answer post I'll mark it correct.

Comment: You aren't checking the return value from accept. You should check to see if "client" is -1 (INVALID_SOCKET) before attempting to "send" anything to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you confirm in comments: `accept` was failing, so there is no address to report.

Answer (score 1):

As also seen in [this PCReview thread](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/accept-always-returns-204-204-204-204-a-t3373709.html), this issue caused by passing an improper value to `accept` in the length field. In the case of the thread this was a null value, <strike>in your case it is a memory address (`&fromlen`).</strike>

<strike>To fix, remove the "address of" operator from `fromlen`.</strike>

As a point of interest, and also from the PCReview thread, the reason for this is:

> 204 is 0xCC, which is the value that the compiler uses for
>   uninitialized stack variables in debug builds to help catch bad
>   accesses. Since you passed NULL, nothing was returned, and sockAddrIn
>   was uninitialized.

#### Edit

As you have mentioned, it is a pointer parameter. I'll leave the rest of the answer here for the sake of interest.

Comment: In MSVC debug mode there are some special value that helps debugging easier which programmers should know http://stackoverflow.com/questions/370195/when-and-why-will-an-os-initialise-memory-to-0xcd-0xdd-etc-on-malloc-free-new